# How to link ffmpeg library by cmake?

Tags: c++, ffmpeg

I want to use ffmpeg library in my c++ program.

I've downloaded ffmpeg source.
 During make&compile process,
i had this error:
UINT64_C not defined!
After some search:

1.Adding the following code to libavutil/common.h

```
#ifndef INT64_C
#define INT64_C(c) (c ## LL)
#define UINT64_C(c) (c ## ULL)
#endif
```

2.`./configure&compile`
had solved that problem.

But now i want to link this library to a simple encoding method by using **cmake** files.
I've tried some sample of CMakeLists.txt but i still have
"undefined refrence " error
many thanks!

- I am working in ubuntu
- using g++ as c++ compiler
- using FFmpeg 2.0.1

Answer (score 1):

you ought to write a finder for `ffmpeg` library, then use it in your cmake-enabled project to detect a correct location and all required files (headers and libs), possible allowing to user to override search results (if we are talking about a really good finder)...

there are plenty tutorials about how to do that over the net. moreover, it will be relatively easy, because `ffmpeg` has a bunch of `.pc` files (at least in my gentoo system), so all that you need is to reuse `pkg-config` to "detect" it... and cmake have a module called `FindPkgConfig` w/ macro `pkg_check_modules` to even more simplify this task. after all, do not forget to use `FindPackageHandleStandardArgs`.

read details in a `/usr/share/cmake/Modules/readme.txt` or google it...

Comment: @paradisalprogrammer you never shared the results :(